# RDz JCICS program failed as Referenced Library cannot be resolved in Mainframe region

Tags: java, eclipse, mainframe, cics

I have included 'ibmzjos' Jar file in java Build Path and jar file is included in Referenced Libraries. In MAINFEST.MF file mentioned the same.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: JavaProject
Bundle-SymbolicName: JavaProject
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: com.ibm.cics.server;version="1.300.0"
Bundle-ClassPath: Referenced Libraries/ibmjzos.jar,
.
CICS-MainClass: com.citi.cards.javaMain
```

In src all error were removed and code looks good. When I created a bundle and execute the program in mainframe server It's failed as  "com.ibm.jzos cannot be resolved:".

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: This tags mainframe and CICS don't really apply here as you are having a JAVA issue

Comment: It is a java CICS issue. I coud't find JCICS Tag.

Comment: Its not a CICS issue though, your error tells us that the issue is with the config.

Comment: @SaggingRufus are you sure it's not a problem with the CICS-configuration? It would be a CICS-issue then.

Comment: @karthi are you sure you need the `ibmjzos.jar` in the `Bundle-ClassPath`? I haven't done anything with CICS-Bundles yet, but aren't the jzos-classes included in the cics-server-package?

Comment: @piet.t Pretty sure its not a CICS issue, they may need to add the path in the mainframe environment (which would make the mainframe tag valid), but I am pretty sure this is not a CICS issue

Comment: @SaggingRufus after doing some reading (see my comment above) it is not an issue with CICS-configuration, but is related to the fact that CICS is used as the OSGi-container. So while I agree that CICS does not have a problem I think the CICS-tag is still warranted.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Updated to include specifics of including JZOS.

The problem here is that the JZOS classes cannot be found. I suspect this is because they're not actually included in your bundle.

To test this, unzip (or otherwise explore) the exported bundle (JAR file). According to your `MANIFEST.MF`, I would expect there to be a folder called `Referenced Libraries` in the root of the JAR, with a file called `ibmjzos.jar` inside that. However, I expect that it does not exist.

To fix this problem, you need to ensure that the `Bundle-ClassPath` is pointing to a real file. Note that `Referenced Libraries` is not a real folder, but rather a pseudo-folder that Eclipse places inside the project that shows what is being brought in on the build path.

1. Make sure ibmjzos.jar is inside the project, such as in the root of the project or in a folder named `lib` (I'll assume the latter).
2. Change the `Bundle-ClassPath` of your `MANIFEST.MF` so that it correctly points to this file:

   ```
   Bundle-ClassPath: lib/ibmjzos.jar
   ```
3. Ensure that the bundle knows to include this JAR in your exported bundle by modifying the property that defines the exported files in the `build.properties` file:

   ```
   bin.includes = META-INF/,\
          .,\
          lib/ibmjzos.jar
   ```

Note that steps 2-3, as well as adding the JAR to your build path so everything compiles in the IDE, can be automated by using the 'Add...' button in the 'Classpath' section of the 'Runtime' tab of your `MANIFEST.MF` editor.

As a further twist, JZOS is a special case because it's so useful on z/OS, and for that reason it's exported by the system bundle from CICS version 5.1 onwards. Therefore, there's not a need to include it in the `Bundle-ClassPath`, but instead you need to have `Import-Package` statements for the relevant packages - for example, you're using `com.ibm.jzos`. To make your IDE happy, you'll need to have a fake bundle in your development environment that exports those packages.

Comment: Tag points to Eclipse, title to Rational Developer for System Z. Take your pick, I suppose :-)